# jQuery function returns an empty string when dropdown selected value is 0

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a dropdown list, When `<option value="0">` is selected, it SHOULD return all items instead of an empty string (this is what I see when doing `console.log()`, if there is some value such as `1,2,3,etc...` it returns a corresponding results.

**I need to retrieve a value `0`, when it's selected, but instead it returns an `an empty string`, while the other numbers are retrieved as they should.**

here is my function:

```
function _getCatsByCom(){
    var com_id_selected = $('select[name=com_id]').val();

    // Next line below with conditional statement is not working, don't know why.
    if(com_id_selected != undefined)
        console.info(com_id_selected);
}
```

Here is a dropdown HTML:

```
<select onchange="template.getCatsByCom();" class="span12" name="com_id">
    <option selected="selected" value="">-- Choose a component --</option>
    <option value="1">Content</option>
    <option value="2">E-commerce</option>
</select>
```

Someone know what I'am doing wrong here ?

In PHP, whenever a function returns the **0** value, it will return's `FALSE`.
[Strict vs. Loose article](http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/strict-vs-loose-comparisons-in-php/)

**== UPDATED ==**

I'am sorry, I did a mistake in PHP, that's why it returned an empty string, so logically it did what it should, it was me who not checked well before asking. Sorry and thanks for pointing me out.

Comment: Idea, make default option `value="-1"`

Comment: .val returns null if no options are selected for a multiple select, or empty string otherwise. not all values.

Comment: try `if(com_id_selected !== undefined)` I think the null is coercing to be undefinedish

Comment: "0" is not undefined, it is "0"

Comment: It's just an example to show what I do not understand, i need to retrieve a value 0, but it returns `an empty string` instead.

Comment: but the code is not referencing "0" its referencing ""

Comment: change the value in the default option to read `value='0'`

Comment: @Orangepill, that depends on which part of the question you believe.

Comment: @Orangepill - what do u mean which default value should I change ? where ?

Comment: `<option selected="selected" value="">-- Choose a component --</option>` should be `<option selected="selected" value="0">-- Choose a component --</option>`

Comment: Why ***should*** it return all items when nothing is selected, is this your personal wish, or what you're expecting? If it's the latter, you'll be disapointed!

Comment: @Orangepill pls answer to my question, because it works! So i could accept your answer. thanks

Comment: Try `var com_id_selected = Number($('select[name=com_id]').val())`, then `if(!com_id_selected) ...`, then is doesn't matter if the option has `value=""` or `value="0"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your current HTML:

```
<select onchange="template.getCatsByCom();" class="span12" name="com_id">
    <option selected="selected" value="">-- Choose a component --</option>
    <option value="1">Content</option>
    <option value="2">E-commerce</option>
</select>
```

The following JS will return all values if the default value (which is `""` not `"0"`) is selected;

```
function _getCatsByCom(){
    var select = $('select[name=com_id]');
    var val = select.val();

    if (val == "") {
        val = select.find('option').map(function () {
            return this.value || undefined; // map will automatically remove the "" from the returned array.
        }).get();
    }

    // Now val will either equal "1", or "2", or "3" etc OR the array of all values.
    console.log(val);
}
```

See this working here; http://jsfiddle.net/y5vPE/. Although I find it bad design that you've now got a variable that is *sometimes* a string, and *sometimes* an array.

... if you want to "correct" it to "0", either change the `value=""` to `value="0"` or change your function;

```
function _getCatsByCom(){
    var select = $('select[name=com_id]');
    var val = select.val();

    if (val == "") {
        val = "0";
    }

    // Now val will either equal "0", "1", "2"... 
    console.log(val);
}
```

Comment: changing a `value=""` to `value="0"` works! Thank you, I made a mistake in PHP, that's why it returns nothing.

Comment: I'm still upvoting this answer as it at least attempts to make sense of 'it SHOULD return all items instead of an empty string'.

Answer (score 2):

Change the

```
<option selected="selected" value="">-- Choose a component --</option>
```

to

```
<option selected="selected" value="0">-- Choose a component --</option>
```